# Spring data mongo DB: Premature end of stream error when connecting to docker mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, docker

I am running latest mongodb image using docker on my local machine. I start it like so

```
docker run -d -p 27017:49153 --name localhost-mongo \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mongo
```

I am also able to log into mongo shell like this

```
docker exec -it localhost-mongo mongo \
--host localhost \
-u admin \
-p password \
--authenticationDatabase admin some-db
```

But when I try to start my spring boot application which connects with Mongodb using spring data mongodb library I get below error immediately

```
[2022-07-14 10:32:03,131] [main] [INFO] [com.mon.dia.log.SLF4JLogger::info] - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56890', transport: 'socket'
[2022-07-14 10:33:31,124] [cluster-ClusterId{value='62cfa34bc781d73d03f70e58', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] [INFO] [com.mon.dia.log.SLF4JLogger::info] - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:579) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:444) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:298) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:258) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:103) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:60) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) [mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

I tried so many ways to at least see what is happening by trying

-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.data=DEBUG
-Dlogging.level.com.mongodb=DEBUG

Debug logs of spring data don't show anything peculiar. No logs from com.mongodb appear on debug level.

Below are my spring configuration properties

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: challengeAPI
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 27017
      username: admin
      password: password
      authentication-database: admin
      max-wait-time: 30000
```

Please help. Totally stuck just trying to connect to local mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you port-mapping from 49153? The documentation states that:

```
The MongoDB server in the image listens on the standard MongoDB port, 27017.
```

Change it to:

```
-p 27017:27017
```

Comment: But how does that matter? For security I will have to map standard 27017 port to something else. And changing port shouldn't give that error. I even tried keeping same port. Nothing changes.

Comment: In your spring connection properties you specify that you are connecting to port 27017, if you don't expose that port from the container you will never be able to connect. Why do you need to change from the standard port for security?